# Django REST Framework update record mixin

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 3.2 and the last version of djangorestframework.

I need to be able to update the values of JobStatus record already crated before.

As example I have

```json
 {
    "id": 1,
    "status_timestamp": "2022-04-07T10:51:42Z",
    "status_activity": "Sync DDT",
    "status_status": "running",
    "launcher": 1
  }
```

and I need to obtain this (in the DB) via API

```json
 {
    "id": 1,
    "status_timestamp": "2022-04-07T11:51:42Z",
    "status_activity": "Sync DDT",
    "status_status": "completed",
    "launcher": 1
  }
```

Can someone help me out?

PS I need to mantain the Token authentication method

---

MODELS

```py
class JobStatus(models.Model):
    status_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    status_activity = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    launcher = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Status"
        verbose_name_plural = "Status list"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.status_timestamp) + " " + self.status_activity
```

URLS

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from apps.api_c import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('alert', views.AlertViewSet)
router.register('jstatus', views.UpdateStatus)

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

VIEWS

```py
class UpdateStatus(viewsets.GenericViewSet, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    """update status"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = StatusSerializer
    #queryset = JobStatus.objects.all()
#TEST1
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
#TEST2
    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer_class.update()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

urls.py

```
from apps.api_c import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('alert', views.AlertViewSet,basename="alert")
router.register('jstatus', views.UpdateStatus, basename="updatestatus")

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

views.py

```py
    class UpdateStatus(viewsets.GenericViewSet, 
                       mixins.ListModelMixin, 
                       mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, 
                       mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
        """update status"""
        authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
        permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
        queryset = JobStatus.objects.all()
        serializer_class = StatusSerializer

        def get_serializer_class(self):

           if self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'put' or self.action == 'patch':
              return StatusUpdateSerializer

       

           return StatusSerializer
```

Then your `StatusUpdateSerializer` would look like:

```
class StatusUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    

    class Meta:

        model = models.JobStatus
        fields =("id","status_timestamp","status_activity","status_status",
        "launcher")
        read_only_fields = ("id","status_timestamp","status_activity",
        "launcher")
```

This should work.

So basically you would need to switch your serializers based on the request method the user is making thus: `def get_serializer_class(self)` method.

In `StatusUpdateSerializer` all the fields are listed.But in the readonly field only list fields that you do not want the user to be able to update or edit.

Comment: Thx for the answer, really useful but it looks generat an error:
in get_default_basename
    assert queryset is not None, '`basename` argument not specified, and could ' \
AssertionError: `basename` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.queryset` attribute.

Comment: have updated my answer by adding ` queryset = JobStatus.objects.all()` also can I see your app urls.py file

Comment: you need to set a base name in your app urls.py file.
I have updated my answer

Comment: router.register('jstatus', views.UpdateStatus, basename='jstatus')
Thx againt, last question (I hope): "detail": "Method \"PUT\" not allowed.", and POST too :(

Comment: `mixins.ListModelMixin`: is for GET, 
`mixins.RetrieveModelMixin`:  is for RETRIEVE i.e get single item
 `mixins.CreateModelMixin`: is for POST,
 `mixins.UpdateModelMixin`: is for PATCH, PUT,
`mixins.DestroyModelMixin`: is for DELETE,

Comment: Sorry for my inexperience, i really don't figure how to make it works, I don't need to let the user select the correct serializer, the api wil only update the value, not showing, not adding.

I've tryed several try but noting works, can you share a snippet how only update?
class UpdateStatus(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
...

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'put' or self.action == 'patch':
            if StatusUpdateSerializer.is_valid(self):
                StatusUpdateSerializer.save(self)
            return StatusUpdateSerializer

Answer (score 0):

I think you had most of the things correct. You need to change the views.py a little bit.

views.py

```
from rest_framework import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.response import Response

class UpdateStatus(viewsets.GenericViewSet, 
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = StatusSerializer
    queryset = JobStatus.objects.all()
    
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'id' in self.request.query_params:
            data = get_object_or_404(self.queryset, id=request.query_params.get('id'))
            serializer = self.serializer_class(data)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

now use the following to do whatever you want:

Get all records:(GET) 127.0.0.1:8000/jstatus/

Get a single record : (GET) 127.0.0.1:8000/jstatus/?id=1

Create a record : (POST)  127.0.0.1:8000/jstatus/1/

Update a record : (PATCH)  127.0.0.1:8000/jstatus/1/

Delete a record : (DELETE) 127.0.0.1:8000/jstatus/1/

I hope this helps.